# Parse Swagger with refs inside jar with openapi4j

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to parse the following swagger file with openapi4j:

```
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.0",
  "info" : {
    "title" : "My Service",
    "version" : "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths" : {
    "/endpoint" : { "$ref" :  "swagger2.json#/paths/get_endpoint" },
  }
}
```

You can see it has a simple ref to another file within the same folder.

I parse the Swagger file with the following:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
openAPI = new OpenApi3Parser().parse(url, false);
```

Locally in my IDE, this works great. The ref is loaded and I am able to validate requests against it with no issues. However, when I jar up the project, it is able to load the initial swagger file fine, but none of the refs. I get the following error:

```
StackTrace: org.openapi4j.core.exception.ResolutionException: Failed to load document from 'swagger2.json'
    at org.openapi4j.core.model.reference.AbstractReferenceResolver.registerDocument(AbstractReferenceResolver.java:118)
    at org.openapi4j.core.model.reference.AbstractReferenceResolver.findReferences(AbstractReferenceResolver.java:92)
    at org.openapi4j.core.model.reference.AbstractReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractReferenceResolver.java:53)
    at org.openapi4j.core.model.v3.OAI3Context.resolveReferences(OAI3Context.java:103)
    at org.openapi4j.core.model.v3.OAI3Context.<init>(OAI3Context.java:73)
    at org.openapi4j.core.model.v3.OAI3Context.<init>(OAI3Context.java:47)
    at org.openapi4j.parser.OpenApi3Parser.parse(OpenApi3Parser.java:34)
    at org.openapi4j.parser.OpenApi3Parser.parse(OpenApi3Parser.java:18)
    at org.openapi4j.parser.OpenApiParser.parse(OpenApiParser.java:53)
```

I'm not sure if this is possible. I assume I may have to copy my project resources out at runtime to the filesystem somewhere to be accessed more easily. I would like to avoid that route if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a bug in openapi4j, which was resolving refs with URI instead of URL. This has been fixed in 0.9